# Triggered Send Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Please kindly help.

My goal is for an email to be send at the same time. (One for Subscriber 1 and the other one for Subscriber 2) using triggered send. I've searched online for it and i don't get any clear answer. I'm quite new to marketing cloud so please kindly help me. (only in a single Journey different DE for Subscriber 1 and Subscriber 2) Subscriber 2 is like a representative of Subscriber1

I wanted to do is when Subscriber1 received email 1 (email 1 will triggersend the same email) to Subscriber 2

Thank you. looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Just to confirm, so is it a standalone triggered send or is it an email in a journey (journey builder)?

Comment: @Adrian Wang you are telling single email send to two Data extensions  at a time by using journey builder or any other?

Comment: @BradSapkota For now what i have tried is API Event via journey builder. EMail 1 containts an ampscript that calls an API Event that leads to the API Journey builder that i made to send Email 2 but the problem is it sends a lot of email like 5 emails on each subs..

Comment: @pkharries yes. What i wanted to do is to send 1 email to two different email address.

Comment: Can you give more detail about how you're collecting the subscribers? Can you post a picture of your journey and any other details?